# Getting values from input text boxes with different classes using wildcard

Tags: jquery, wildcard

after googling, searching on the forum and trying many different alternatives, i wasn't able to find a solution to this, even tho it looks so simple!
I need to get the values of different classes starting with the same string

```
<div id="home"></div>
<input type="text" class="var_in_1">
<input type="text" class="var_in_2">

$(document).on('change', '[class^="var_in"]', function () {
     $("#home").append($('[class^="var_in"]').val() + " --- ");
});
```

I created a fiddle to better explain my issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/5zdpq1wL/
as you can see, it gets the first value only!!

Comment: You'll need to iterate on the inputs instead of using a wildcard selector to get the combined value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var allValues = $('[class^="var_in"]').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get(); //or toArray()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4o1xg2qw/

As stated in the comments, you need to iterate all elements that match your selector.

To add your `---` separator, just join the values:

```
console.log(allValues.join(' --- '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution

```
$(document).on('change', '[class^="var_in"]', function () {
    var content = '';
    $('[class^="var_in"]').each(function(){
       if(this.value) content += (this.value + ' --- ');
    });
    $("#home").html(content);
});
```

- I have replaced $("#home").append(content) by $("#home").html(content) because I am not sure what you really want.